# How can I pull Minimum Password Length policy from Windows 10 registry?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry

Trying to pull the minimum password length policy information from the registry, but it appears that is no longer possible on later versions of W10?

There are a number of documented answers out there that direct you to `MinPwdLen` (https://superuser.com/questions/1468788/where-is-the-minimum-password-length-policy-information-stored-on-windows-10), but none of these are created on the W10 systems I am testing on (20H2, non-domain joined).

Even using Procmon, I am not seeing how the setting is getting stored when editing that policy using the local security policy editor.

[image: local policy editor]

Comment: I suggest to use the command "net accounts" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows does not use the registry for storing and managing security policies.  Security policies are stored in the security database.  You can export them with the below command, and search for the line that starts with: MinimumPasswordLength =

```
secedit /export /areas SECURITYPOLICY /cfg C:\DirName\FileName.txt
```

Comment: And just for completeness, here is the default location: `%windir%\security\database\secedit.sdb`